# crontab no funciona en lubuntu 18.04.01

Tags: ubuntu, crontab

Se que esta pregunta la han hecho infinidad de veces, y tengo varias horas viendo posibles soluciones y ninguna encaja con lo que me pasa, así que me animé a hacer esta pregunta, porque debe ser un detalle, pero no logro verlo.

mi script

```
cat elorat /home/elorat/tareas/hora.sh
```

.

```
archivo='/home/elorat/logs/pagina/hora.log'
echo "" >> $archivo
echo date >> $archivo
echo ""
echo date
```

lo listo:

```
$ ll hora.sh
```

.

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 elorat elorat 675 ene 13 20:12 hora.sh*
```

Lo agrego para que se ejecute cada minuto con mi perfil de usuario:

```
$ crontab -e
```

.

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
# 
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
# 
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').# 
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
# 
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
# 
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
# 
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# 
# m h  dom mon dow   command

*/1 * * * * elorat /home/elorat/tareas/hora.sh
```

y esta es la salida del log del sistema `tail -f /var/log/syslog`

```
Jan 13 20:26:01 Aspire CRON[5110]: (elorat) CMD (elorat /home/elorat/tareas/hora.sh)
Jan 13 20:26:01 Aspire sSMTP[5111]: Creating SSL connection to host
Jan 13 20:26:02 Aspire sSMTP[5111]: SSL connection using ECDHE_RSA_CHACHA20_POLY1305
Jan 13 20:26:05 Aspire sSMTP[5111]: Sent mail for elorat@Aspire (221 2.0.0 closing connection y78sm22806913vsc.6 - gsmtp) uid=1000 username=elorat outbytes=618
```

*Alguna idea que pueda ser?*

**ACTUALIZACION:**

No existe el archivo `/var/log/crontab`, pero ejecuté el comando:

```
$ journalctl -u cron.service
```

y esta es la salida...

```
.....
ene 13 21:37:01 Aspire CRON[8569]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user elorat by (uid=0)
ene 13 21:37:02 Aspire sSMTP[8571]: Creating SSL connection to host
ene 13 21:37:02 Aspire sSMTP[8571]: SSL connection using ECDHE_RSA_CHACHA20_POLY1305
ene 13 21:37:05 Aspire sSMTP[8571]: Sent mail for elorat@Aspire (221 2.0.0 closing connection r8sm29995647uan.0 - gsmtp) uid=1000 username=elorat outbytes=618
ene 13 21:37:05 Aspire CRON[8569]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user elorat
ene 13 21:38:01 Aspire CRON[8595]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user elorat by (uid=0)
ene 13 21:38:01 Aspire sSMTP[8597]: Creating SSL connection to host
ene 13 21:38:02 Aspire sSMTP[8597]: SSL connection using ECDHE_RSA_CHACHA20_POLY1305
ene 13 21:38:06 Aspire sSMTP[8597]: Sent mail for elorat@Aspire (221 2.0.0 closing connection g195sm37329398vka.5 - gsmtp) uid=1000 username=elorat outbytes=618
ene 13 21:38:06 Aspire CRON[8595]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user elorat
ene 13 21:39:01 Aspire CRON[8653]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
ene 13 21:39:01 Aspire CRON[8654]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user elorat by (uid=0)
ene 13 21:39:01 Aspire CRON[8653]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
ene 13 21:39:01 Aspire sSMTP[8657]: Creating SSL connection to host
ene 13 21:39:02 Aspire sSMTP[8657]: SSL connection using ECDHE_RSA_CHACHA20_POLY1305
ene 13 21:39:05 Aspire sSMTP[8657]: Sent mail for elorat@Aspire (221 2.0.0 closing connection n15sm35139864uao.18 - gsmtp) uid=1000 username=elorat outbytes=618
ene 13 21:39:05 Aspire CRON[8654]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user elorat
ene 13 21:40:01 Aspire CRON[8898]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user elorat by (uid=0)
ene 13 21:40:01 Aspire sSMTP[8900]: Creating SSL connection to host
ene 13 21:40:02 Aspire sSMTP[8900]: SSL connection using ECDHE_RSA_CHACHA20_POLY1305
ene 13 21:40:05 Aspire sSMTP[8900]: Sent mail for elorat@Aspire (221 2.0.0 closing connection w65sm64706287vsc.16 - gsmtp) uid=1000 username=elorat outbytes=618
ene 13 21:40:05 Aspire CRON[8898]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user elorat
```

Comment: Dale al `/var/log/crontab.log` a ver que error marca

Comment: amigo ve la respuesta en la actualización de la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

por lo visto en lubuntu 18.04.01 este debe ser el script (sin el usuario)

```
 */1 * * * * /home/elorat/tareas/hora.sh
```

Comment: rrg1459, para organizar el código que coloques en las preguntas y/o respuestas, selecciona el código y presiona ctrl + k. [Mira esta y otras funcionalidades para formatear lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Este [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) también es de mucha ayuda. Saludos.